Does XNAV (Pulsar navigation) give an absolute position, or a position in relation to the arbitrary inertial reference the system initiates with?
With Pulsar-based navigation (XNAV) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsar-based_navigation , X-ray pulsar signals from a multiplicity of pulsars are used to determine the position of a spacecraft. It is somewhat analogous to GPS, where precisely timed signals from satellites in known orbits are used to determine the receiver’s position.
Since the apparent pulse rate of pulsars is practically constant and can be observed with high accuracy, measurement of the phase angle between pulses can provide accurate measures of change in radial position between the spacecraft and the pulsar.
This is analogous to the DECCA radio navigation system which used phase comparison as opposed to pulse timing, as LORAN did.
However, because the distance to a given pulsar is not known with high accuracy, only pulse arrival phase changes can be calculated, not absolute distance. In addition, there is no way to measure the absolute period of a given pulsar since the observed period will be affected by Doppler shift.
There is no privileged “correct” inertial reference system in the universe, so I assume the XNAX system initiates on whichever is the convenient inertial reference system for the spacecraft, then “counts” pulsar phase changes from the starting position to give a position with respect to the starting position.
Is this correct? Does XNAV give a position relative to the arbitrary starting inertial frame rather than in relation to the pulsars themselves?

I don't understand how XNAV works, but modern celestial reference systems usually refer to the coordinate axes of an ICRF system. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Celestial_Reference_System_and_its_realizations

I really don't understand the distinction between phase angle and timing. Is it because one must detect the time of many noisy, jittery pulses in a row and somehow get an average time (modulo the known period)?

Different but somewhat related (and some answers/comments may have information helpful towareds an answer here): Is NICER/SEXTANT the first civilian "spacecraft" to determine its own position in space without GPS or uplinked data? and How can spacecraft navigate without contact from Earth? and this answer to Can the James Webb Space Telescope's position be determined using GNSS? And if not, how is this done?

@uhoh they are often used synonymously; the difference is phase angle repeats every 360 degrees so if you don't keep track of it at higher resolution than the period, you won't distinguish 360 from 720 from 1080 degrees; it's excellent for establishing very small time differences, but you must keep a more coarse time separately. Say frequency=1Hz. You'll easily tell 0.05s apart from 0.06s, but telling apart 100.06s apart from 101.06s requires a separate clock or counter.

The frame is tied to the inertial frame of the Solar System.
The pulsars XNAV uses are detectable by ground-based radio observatories. The phase difference between x-ray and radio observations measures the difference between the distances of the x-ray and radio observatories to the pulsar.
The radio observatories are at known locations on Earth, and Earth's position and orientation in the Solar System are well determined from other observations. The reduction of the x-ray observations may bring these together in whatever solar/terrestrial frame you choose, since the relationships between the frames are known.

Can you support this by linking to sources that confirm this? For example see Is NICER/SEXTANT the first civilian "spacecraft" to determine its own position in space without GPS or uplinked data? where I seem to assert (rightly or wrongly) that this demonstration was NOT tied to radio observations on Earth. "Help me Mr. Wizard!"

@uhoh https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0094576520304070?via%3Dihub, but you have to pay for it.

Is this the same document? https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/20190031975

@uhoh It's not the same one, but it has what you want. See Figure 5. The "almanac" comes from radio observations.

@uhoh Note also that there was a dependency on GPS. NICER lacks a high stability clock oscillator. It emulates one by checking its seven low stability oscillators once per second against GPS time. In a real XNAV application, out of range of GPS, you'd need a high stability oscillator.
